# Space cartoon from the 80s or 90s

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

It was a space cartoon, sort of like a cross between Star Wars and Battlestar Galactica. Lots of star fighters and aliens. Here are the major things I remember:

- The main villain used to be a good guy but was left for dead and rebuilt by the bad guys. This is shown in opening. He is bald, wears a mask and a cape and has a thing on his chest (I think). I think he forgot who he was ultimately a puppet?
- The second notable bad guy was a robot that looked very similar to the bug people that Vegeta kills in Dragon Ball Z. In one episode the good guys find his head covered in something in a crab tank.
- The bad guys use vehicles that have legs and I'm sure they called them crab tanks.
- In one episode some Jabba the Hut look-a-like absorbed the leaders of the good guys and the bad guys in to his body so they feel what he felt.
- One of the good guys is like a werewolf but in reverse. Whenever he is on his planet he looks like a normal human. And his wife or girlfriend lives there.
- The opening explained the show; bad guys attack, one of the good guys is captured and turned into a Darth Vader-ish leader of the bad guys.

Can't remember much more, will add if anything comes to mind.

Answer (score 7):

It might be [Space Strikers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Strikers) (1995). The series is famous for mixing 2D and 3D animation, you may recognize this feature.

Summary (from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488469/), [90s cartoon wiki](http://90scartoons.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Strikers) and [Encyclopedia of Television Shows](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=YX_daEhlnbsC&pg=PA1000&lpg=PA1000&dq=cartoon%20werewolf%20space&source=bl&ots=R4wJlmXI8t&sig=SPDeWDwJr9gwi3183Os6DVYzHP0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF1e2i0-HWAhXFHJAKHa4zD-kQ6AEIdTAZ#v=onepage&q=cartoon%20werewolf%20space&f=false))

> In the far future, Captain Nemo (descendant of the original Nemo) must fight against Master Phantom, an old friend of their academy times in Terrestrial Commando Alliance who had an accident that twisted his body and his mind forever.
>
> ***Before adopting the identity of Master Phantom, he was once human, and a close friend of Nemo's*** when the two were youths at the space academy. However, ***Phantom believes Nemo deliberately abandoned him on an asteroid*** during a meteor shower. Wounded, ***his life was saved by the evil Metallic, who turned him into a Darth Vader-type figure***, part-man, part-machine. The consuming ambition of Master Phantom is now to establish dominion in space and to secure his vengeance against Nemo
>
> With the Nautilus' crew Ned Land, Malcolm, Diana, Yonnak (a super intelligent alien dolphin), Victory the Solarian (a little and ghostly floating alien), ***Dacar (a blue werewolf)*** and Algren-18 (a three head robot), Nemo crosses the deep outer space in the endless searching for Master Phantom and his army of robots.

**Phantom and Metallic**

[image]

**Crab-like vehicle**
[image]

**Captain Nemo and his crew**
[image]